# constant + sinusoid frequency recognition

Tags: complex-numbers, signal-processing

I am working on some problem relating to radars. The problem boils down to finding the frequency of the complex exponential in a constant + complex exponential + noise model. I found some papers on sinusoid recognition but they use the sinusoid + noise model only. I tried to come up with an approach myself. It worked fine without noise but with noise it crashes. My approach actually increases the variance of the noise (because it involves differencing) and being in a SNR limited region I can't work with that. Just wanted to inquire whether this problem has been explored by anybody else in any field. Another point about the model is that the constant term is greater in magnitude than the magnitude of the exponential. I have also included the physics forums link for what people replied to my post there.

Thanks Khurram

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/finding-the-frequency-of-sinuosid-in-a-constant-sinusoid.885112/

Comment: I'd take the FFT of the samples and discard the first bin when searching for the peak frequency. This method can give too rough an estimate, so you can refine it using something like: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259141907_Frequency_estimation_of_a_sinusoidal_signal_via_a_three-point_interpolated_DFT_method_with_high_image_component_interference_rejection_capability.